# Asp.net is it possible to check page_load a click event is triggered?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When a button is clicked, I would like to check whether a button is clicked in my page_load. Is this possible? I am using asp.net 2.0 C#

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about why you want to do this? It sounds like you might be going about things the wrong way if you are asking this question.

Comment: I have a menu which load a user controls in panel A. A user control can load another user control in panel B. So after a postback I have to reload the user controls in both panels. This is done by storing the name of the user control in the viewstate. The reload part is handled in the page_load. But when a  menu item is clicked then first both user controls are reloaded (in the page_load) and after that my menu item event is fired and loads a control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the `IsPostBack` flag to see if it was a postback rather than an initial load. This may be what you're after. Also, you can check the `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` from which you can obtain information about the control that raised the event and therefore find out if it was one of your buttons from there.

Comment: Thnx. I think I was looking for Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]

Answer (score 1):

The button click event will fire after the page load event has.  That being said, you can always check the http header to see what value is being pushed back through the request.form event.  The button id will be in there if it has been fired.

Comment: Yes I know. But I want to know in my page_load whether an event is raised.

Comment: oh I see what you are saying now.

Answer (score 0):

I can think a work around by creating a hidden field and changing the value when a certain button is clicked and  checking it value in Page_Load.